# Can anyone give me some help editing the Abe html?

Tags: blockchain-explorer, abe

I've got Abe running, but would really like to get the page looking nicer. I've managed to change the logo, but would like to change the title and change some colours and fonts, maybe add some more text.

I know this HTML is generated on the fly, from abe.py? I've tried editing that, but it doesn't seem to effect my page at all.

Comment: Are you re-running abe.py each time you edit it?

Comment: I do CTRL + C to break and then start Abe.

Comment: Hmmm... you're editing `DEFAULT_TEMPLATE` to change the HTML, right?

Comment: I think so, yeh. The bit directly underneath,

    # Abe-generated content should all be valid HTML and XHTML fragments.
    # Configurable templates may contain either.  HTML seems better supported
    # under Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I use CSS only.

Try this: Use default Abe html layout and use the following modified abe.css. The only changes needed are logo margins and color/font palette. Name your logo the same as abe's (logo32.png - makes things easier)

[Click here for the modified abe.css](http://kobocoin.com/abe.css)

I modified the previous abe.py but found with the current version I'm using (0.8pre) that css is much easier. Most objects on the page can be manipulated.